# Self invoking function

Tags: javascript

I'm a little confused over the execution flow of self invoking functions in javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>

    var test = function () {
        alert("Test1##");
    }

    var test2 = function () {
        alert("Test2!!");
    }

    (function () {
        test();
    })();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Result: `Test2!!`. 
I expected it to alert `Test1##` since I'm calling that particular function.

However, if I include semicolon after each functions `test`and `test2`, the result is how I expect it to be: It would alert `Test1##`.

How does it work?

Comment: JavaScript is not a whitespace-delineated language. Put the semicolons in.

Comment: "*However, if I include semicolon after each function...the result is how I expect it to be*" - and that's why using semi-colons is a good idea.

Comment: You must include semicolons after declaring a variable in javaScript otherwise it may print unexpected results.


    var test = function () {
            alert("Test1##");
        };
    
        var test2 = function () {
            alert("Test2!!");
        };
    
        (function () {
            test();
        })();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use some semicolons. Otherwise the statements get blended.

Why I think this is happening is that the function that calls `test` isn't getting called at all, but it's being passed to `test2` as the first argument.

You can see that behavior here: https://jsfiddle.net/ssgagr3k/

Comment: It does work properly with semicolons, I want to understand how the js treats it when there's no semicolon. 
If the execution starts from the first function defined, why does it not print the statements in the first function and the ones that follow, until it encounters a semicolon?

Comment: Daniel,  You are correct.  This can be tested by calling `console.log(arguments)` from within test2's function. Edit: *as well.  (your test works too I suppose :P)

Comment: Excellent example Daniel. Now I have more questions. Even if you remove the `test()` call in self invoking function, the result is still same. The call inside self invoking function doesn't seem to matter. Also, how is the `val` being passed to `test2()`? Appreciate your answer.

Comment: @RohitPujar basically `test2` is treated as an self invoking function.

Comment: *Maybe* [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vt8tf56v/1) is helpful in making it understandable? That or it'll only make it more confusing.

Comment: @JosephMarikle now the last set of parens are invoking another function.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. step 1: call `function () { alert("Test2!!"); }` and pass it the parameter `function () {test();}`. Can you please explain why is `test2()` being called instead of `test1()`. How does the execution flow begin?

Comment: 1: `function () { alert("Test2!!"); }` is passed `function () { test(); }` and executed. It doesn't matter what was passed, because it doesn't do anything with parameters. 2: After it finishes executing, the flow runs into another `()` at the very end, so it tries to execute whatever was returned by the last statement. In the original code, it just errors out. That's why I added a return with a function. To show that it was trying to execute something but the first function didn't originally return anything. Here's another example using a seperate function: https://jsfiddle.net/vt8tf56v/2/

Comment: Thanks for the example, I'm getting the perspective but with more questions. You say that `step 1: call `function () { alert("Test2!!"); }` and pass it the parameter `function () {test();}``, however if I include semicolon in `test1()`, only `test1()` is called. Which means when semicolon is included, it is not calling the `test2()`. So the execution begins with first function in the body?

Comment: In short, can you please explain me the flow of execution in this: https://jsfiddle.net/vt8tf56v/2/

Comment: @RohitPujar the best thing to do is run it with a debugger and you can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Debugged a simple js, put the comments here https://jsfiddle.net/6tn4zwkc/2/

Comment: @RohitPujar For your commented fiddle, the lines you mentioned are not executed because `test` is never called.  It would be called if the final closure were ever executed, but it isn't.  Instead it's passed as a parameter to test2, but test2 doesn't take a parameter, so it ignores it.